# Positional based, strategical card games?

Tags: playing-cards, tactics

There was a CCG called [Warlord: Saga of the Storm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warlord_%28card_game%29) that I played briefly in its relevancy. It was the only CCG I played where positioning was a main element. Ranged attacks, etc. The accompanying image is low quality, but shows an example of unit placement based on ranks.

Mostly I am just wondering if this concept saw light in other **card games**. A board game like [Mage Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mage_Wars) uses placement with cards, but also requires a board.

I also wonder if there are traditional playing card games with the element of strategical card placement?

[image]

Comment: The On the Edge CCG used ranks and files that had an effect on gameplay.

Comment: Why is this on hold?

Comment: Pixel Tactics does this.

Comment: @user30903 it is flagged because it's asking for recommendations, essentially a poll, and that's frowned on here

Comment: A better way to answer this sort of question would be to figure out the relevant tag on boardgamegeek, and search games with that tag. Unfortunately in this case I couldn't find a relevant tag or set thereof, but I would still argue that the bgg tag/discovery system is the right approach for this type of information, rather than asking here.

Comment: I do find a gray line between "best 3 player card games?" and "know of any other games in this very niche genre that I can't even think of more than 2-3 others". However, gray line or not, I do agree BGG is a nice place to ask this sort of thing.